# nodejs nodemailer create events

Tags: node.js, events, nodemailer

I use nodejs nodemail to send mail so I have in a part I want to create event error and success when a mail is send instead of using the callback

```
var util = require('util');
var event = require('events');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTansport("SMTP", {
     service: "GMAIL",
     auth: {
        user : "mail@mail.com",
        pass : "pass"
           }
     });
mail.exports = function(from, to, subject ...){
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.subject = subject;
    ....

    this.send = function(){
        var options = {
            from = this.from;
            to = this.to;

        };
        var obj = this.send;
        event.Eventemitter.call(obj);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(options, function(err, success) {
            if(err){
                obj.emit('error', err);
            }
            if(success){
                obj.emit('success', success);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

then a call the mail service

```
var Mail = require('./mail');
var mail = new Mail();
    mail.from = "email@mail.com";
    mail.to = "email@mail.com";
    ...
    mail.send(); //the mail is send
```

the mail is send but I don't know if the mail send or not

```
    mail.send()
     .on("error", function(err){
         console.log("Mail not send");
     })
     .on("success", function(success){
         console.log("Mail send");
     });
```

I followed the following tuto
http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the callbacks? You would want to be sure the success & error callbacks are registered before you send the email.

Comment: when I run mail.send() I can't know if the mail was send or not. so I want to add event error and success when I run smtpTransport.sendMail(). So when I listen error and success on mail.send() I can know if mail was send or not

Comment: Did you manage to get this working @goten?

Comment: sorry I was little busy last day. Yes, I still can't get exactly what I wanted at the beginning but I find with your help something good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTansport("SMTP", {
     service: "GMAIL",
     auth: {
        user : "mail@mail.com",
        pass : "pass"
           }
     });

module.exports = function(from, to, subject){
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.events = new events.EventEmitter();
    //....
    this.send = function(){
        var options = {
            from : this.from,
            to : this.to

        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(options, function(err, success) {
            if(err){
                this.events.emit('error', err);
            }
            if(success){
                this.events.emit('success', success);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
var Mail = require('./mail');
var mail = new Mail();
mail.from = "email@mail.com";
mail.to = "email@mail.com";

mail.events.on("error", function(err){
         console.log("Mail not send");
});
mail.events.on("success", function(success){
         console.log("Mail send");
});

mail.send();
```

I don't have access to gmail at the moment to test the sending etc, but this should work in principal.

There are various syntax issues in your initial example which I fixed.

The main thing to bare in mind is that you need to expose the EventEmitter to the client code so that they can register for callbacks and be sure to register the callbacks before sending the email.

You can do this without using the EventEmitter as well, by passing in success and failure callback functions. Which will make it a bit simpler.

```
module.exports = function(params){
    this.from = params.from;
    this.to = params.to;
    this.subject = params.subject;
    this.successCallback = params.successCallback;
    this.errorCallback= params.errorCallback;

    this.send = function(){
        var options = {
            from : this.from,
            to : this.to    
        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(options, function(err, success) {
            if(err){
                this.errorCallback(err);
            }
            else{
                this.successCallback(success);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Calling it looks like this:

```
var Mail = require('./mail');
var mail = new Mail({
  from : "email@mail.com", 
  to : "email@mail.com", 
  subject : "subject", 
  successCallback : function(success){
            console.log("Mail send");
         },
  errorCallback : function(err){
           console.log("Mail not send");
        }
});

mail.send();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was looking more for somethings like the first one. But the second is also quite interesting for something else  I want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: params.data.service,
    auth: {
        user: params.data.user,
        pass: params.data.pass
    }
});

/*
 * Events
 */
var event = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

/*
 * Export of the module mail
 */
function Mail(from, to, cc, bcc, replyTo, subject, text, html, generateTextFromHTML, headers){

    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.cc = cc;
    this.bcc = bcc;
    this.replyTo = replyTo;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.text = text;
    this.html = html;
    this.generateTextFromHTML = generateTextFromHTML;
    this.headers = headers;

    var self = this;
    event.call(self);
    this.send =  function() {

        var options = {
            from    : this.from,
            to      : this.to,
            cc      : this.cc,
            bcc     : this.bcc,
            replyTo : this.replyTo,
            subject : this.subject,
            text    : this.text,
            html    : this.html,
            generateTextFromHTML : this.generateTextFromHTML,
            headers : this.headers

        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(options, function(err, success){
            if(err){
                self.emit('error', err);
            }
            if(success){
                self.emit('success', success);
            }
        });

    };
}

util.inherits(Mail, event);

module.exports = Mail;
```

Calling :

```
  var Mail = require('mail');
  var mail = new Mail({
      from : "email@mail.com", 
      to : "email@mail.com", 
      subject : "subject"
      });
      mail.send();
      mail
        .on('success', function(res){
            console.log(res.message);
        });
```